# How I can secure an approval number from the General Administration of Press and Publication of China?

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

Apple requires I do this to have my game for sale in China.

App Store Connect only links to this document in Chinese http://www.sapprft.gov.cn/sapprft/contents/6588/298011.shtml

Apple Updated Link : http://www.nppa.gov.cn/nppa/channels/301.shtml